# How do I export a picture from Lightroom without the original?

Tags: lightroom, file-transfer, lightroom-5

The JPG file is in lightroom with every detail but I cannot export the file because I transfered the file from a friends flash drive.

The error message I get is:

"“DSCN1663.JPG” could not be used because the original file could not be found. Would you like to locate it?"

I don't have the "original" because my friend deleted the pictures.

I could screenshot the image but wanted to look for a better way!

Comment: You may want to review how LR manages its files. The catalog contains a preview, a sometimes smaller version of the whole file, so that some work may be done without the entire file available. With LR5 and smart previews this has become more powerful, but the catalog is separate from your files. When you import your files pay attention to if you're "adding," "moving," or "copying" as each is distinctly different in how they're handled at the time and in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I have LR5 and just tried this and it didn't complain to me, but you could try [this](http://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/extract-previews-lightroom-4.html) script provided by Adobe (for use with LR4, but maybe it still works).